# ExoPlayer does not support MPEG-1 Audio Codec?

Tags: android, codec

Most of the videos served by my provider (server) have never had any audio or video issues.

However, some stream currently have no audio at all, and I think this is a problem with the ExoPlayer I developed.

I've been using it by creating an instance of ExoPlayer in a really simple way (creating a Mediasource using the static method of the commonly used Progressive Mediasource), and I'm confident that I've never used a simple enough way to use SimpleExoPlayer (to support subtitles). There are some cases)

I found out about the codec of this video that it is Mpeg Audio Layer 1/2 (mpga). However, no precedent could be found. Problems caused by the codec

```
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(context);
    ExoPlayer.Builder builder = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context);
    builder.setTrackSelector(trackSelector);

    DefaultRenderersFactory factory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(context);
    builder.setRenderersFactory(factory);
    int bufferSegmentSize = 3; //
    int bufferSegmentCount = 10; //
    int minBufferMs = bufferSegmentSize * bufferSegmentCount * 1000; //

    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
            .setBufferDurationsMs(minBufferMs, minBufferMs, 1500, 1500) // 버퍼링 관련 설정
            .setTargetBufferBytes(-1)
            .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true)
            .createDefaultLoadControl();
    builder.setLoadControl(loadControl);



    player = builder.build();
    player.setMediaSource(getMediaSource(context));
    player.prepare();
    player.play();
```

here is my code.
Do I need to add any additional work to the process of building my ExoPlayer Instance?

I desperately need help